# Serializing every object and its properties in a collection to XML

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have a collection of objects, with properties. I want to use XStream to serialize it to XML and in a file.

I have the following code:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
abstractStrategy.GetObject();

String Path = "C:\\Objects.xml";
File file = new File(Path);
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

However, when I run this code, the call to `getobject()` gets an object with properties, but the xml that is spitted out is one line with `<list/>`

What am I doing wrong?

```
xstream.toXML(abstractStrategy.Components.get(0).IPAddress, outputStream);
```

Comment: urgh... you really should stop using c# naming conventions in your java, it's giving me motion-sickness.

Comment: You'll have to show us the class of the object you are trying to serialise. Does it contain a `java.util.Properties` object?

Comment: Your code doesn't allow to diagnose problem. You're referencing the objects no one except you knows the class of.